# Preventing a student from voting twice using the id of the student

Tags: php, mysql

Please i am working on an online voting system. i want to prevent double voting by the students using the ID of the student. can anyone help me out how to do that. The login will require a students id and a unique password the system will generate and sent to the mails to use to login. how can i track a student's id and prevent him or her from voting the second time. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I know our school used a Google Form with Google Apps Script to track votes and prevent duplicates. I'm not sure of the details of implementation, but I know it worked.